# Case statement to replace where clause

Tags: sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT IMALAC.DANOCENBROJ,
       '1' as REZULTAT
FROM IMALAC
LEFT JOIN RACUNIL
    ON IMALAC.ID = IMALACID
WHERE RACUNIL.STATUS = 1
    AND (
        RACUNIL.VIDSMETKA = 1
        OR RACUNIL.VIDSMETKA = 5
        OR RACUNIL.VIDSMETKA = 7
        OR RACUNIL.VIDSMETKA = 8
        OR RACUNIL.VIDSMETKA = 9
    )
```

I want to rewrite the query, so that it would include a `case` statement, which is supposed to act as an `if`/`else` statement for the `where` part.

In particular, the condition should be:

1. if code after `where` clause is `true` then `REZULTAT` = 1
2. else 0

Anyone?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Are you aware that your current where clause turns your `left join` into an `inner join`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want this:

```
SELECT  IMALAC.DANOCENBROJ, 
        CASE
            WHEN RACUNIL.STATUS = 1 AND RACUNIL.VIDSMETKA IN (1,5,7,8,9)
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END as REZULTAT
FROM IMALAC
LEFT JOIN RACUNIL
ON IMALAC.ID = IMALACID
;
```

Comment: I'm impressed at understanding the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've been impressed by that same ability in a lot of your answers